# Append from a string list until a semi-colon in Python 3.9

Tags: python, string, list

How do I append from multiple string lists I don't know what are, but I'll need to separate into new different lists using the semi-colon as a separator in Python? For example, if I'm given the following string list:

```
example = ['pineapple; lemon; watermelon']
```

I need to get the following results:

```
list1 = ["pineapple"]
list2 = ["lemon"]
list3 = ["watermelon"]
```

and append with the same logic and order when given a new string

P.S.: Since there are no patterns in the list I'll be given, I can't just use

```
list1.append(example[0:number])
```

for the task, which is what I've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need each variable to be a list containing a single string (which is unusual but consistent with your input), you could do this:

```
list1,list2,list3 = ([s] for s in example[0].split('; '))
```

*This works with the example given but it begs the questions: Can your original list contain more than one string ?  Can the strings contain more (or fewer) than 3 parts separated by semicolons ? Do you really need lists with a single string in them as the output ?  Where in your question is there an 'append' operation to be done and under what rules ?*

With answers to all these questions, your request could be interpreted very differently.  For example, append 3 parts of each string in the source list to the corresponding 3 lists.  in which case you could have an input and output like this:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []

example = ['pineapple; lemon; watermelon',
           'apple; orange; banana',
           'grape; peach; pear']

lists = [list1,list2,list3]
for aString in example:
    for aList,part in zip(lists, aString.split('; ')):
        aList.append(part)
```

Output:

```
list1: ['pineapple', 'apple', 'grape']
list2: ['lemon', 'orange', 'peach']
list3: ['watermelon', 'banana', 'pear']
```

Answer (score 2):

you want

```py
output_lists = [list(map(str.strip, s.split(';'))) for s in example]
```

then your desired results are `output_lists[i][j]`, where `i` is the position of the original list in the example, and `j` is the position in the string that got split.

explanation:

- `s.split(';')` takes your semicolon delimited string and returns a list of the elements
- `map(str.strip, s.split(';'))` removes whitespace from the beginning and end of every element in the list of strings
- `list(map())` turns the output of `map` into a `list` (`map` returns a python [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types))
- `[list(map()) for s in example]` is a python [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

If for some reason you need your output to be singleton lists then you can do

```py
def singleton_strip(to_strip):
    return [to_strip.strip()]

output_lists = [list(map(singleton_strip, s.split(';'))) for s in example]
```

If you know all elements will always be separated by `'; '` then you can do `s.split('; ')` and drop the `list(map())` construction.